# Add new key value pair to firebase map

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Current situation**

I have the following cloud firestore DB:

[image]

I'm working on Python and currently using the following code to update it:

```
city_ref.update({"test": {"three": 200}})
```

I know the exact path to the data field and map to add data.

**What I would like to achieve**

I want to be able to add data and update it to following.

I would like to archive just by one write: meaning without the process of reading from database, appending data to read data, and updating database.

[image]

**Problem**

My current code code updates the whole map as below.

[image]

How could I add data while leaving the existing data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write to a document, you need to know the exact, complete path to that document and construct a reference to it (the `city_ref` in your code). If you know the path and have a reference, you can write to the document without first reading it.

But if you don't know a part of the path (most commonly the ID of the document you want to update), then you will have to read the document(s) from the collection in order to be able to update them.

---

Based on the update you provided: your current instruction tells the database to update the top-level `test` field with the value you specify. But what you want to do is [write a nested field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), which takes using `.` notation:

```
city_ref.update({"test.three" : 200})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have complete path to the document but I can't find a way to simply add new key value pair. On some question I seen people use "add" instead of "update" but when I try it I get 'DocumentReference' object has no attribute 'add' error.

Comment: This is getting confusing. Can you edit your question to include a single [minimal yet standalone code snippet that allows us to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and a clear description of the problem you get when you run that code (including any error message and stack trace)?

Comment: thank you for your comment, updated it the question.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I added an update to my answer.